Setting expectations for some values of argument only
Let's say a have a mocked method void foo(int).
The method is called a few times in the code under test, for the given test I am only interested in the call that is made with argument value, let's say, 10.
I'd like to be able to write
EXPECT_CALL(d_fooer, foo(10));

and ignore other calls to, say, foo(1) and foo(2).
Instead,  I get a test failure on foo(1) because the mock is called with unexpected value.
To avoid failure I have to add
EXPECT_CALL(d_fooer, foo(1));
EXPECT_CALL(d_fooer, foo(2));

which clutters my tests.
Is there a way to ignore those?
